# Get length of ADPropertyValueCollection, or check if empty/not set

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am iterating through a list of AD users and reporting on their proxyAddresses. I would like to be able to check for length 0 or check for null/not set. I used the GetType function to figure out the proxyAddresses attribute is of type ADPropertyValueCollection. But looking through the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adpropertyvaluecollection-1?view=activedirectory-management-10.0 ) I cannot find any way to get the length or check it for null/empty.

Here is my current code, I simply check it for the built-in PowerShell $null variable, but it does not catch when the proxyAddresses attribute is not set on the user:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=Domain,DC=local' -Properties "proxyAddresses"

$outputStr = ''
foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($user.DistinguishedName -inotmatch "OU1|OU2|OU3") {
        # Skips users not in OU's we care about
        continue
    }

    if ($user.proxyAddresses -eq $null) {
        # This never fires, despite users existing with the attribute not set
        Write-Output "WARNING: User $($user.Name) found with proxyAddresses not set."
    }

    $outputStr += "Proxy addresses for $($user.Name)`r`n"
    foreach ($addr in $user.proxyAddresses) {
        $outputStr += "$($addr)`r`n"
    }
    
    $outputStr += "`r`n"
}

Out-File -FilePath 'c:\data\aliases.txt' -Encoding utf8 -InputObject $outputStr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting, it appears if they don't have proxyaddresses set, the property is not returned with the user object. You should just be able to test for the existence of proxyaddresses like this.

```
if (!$user.proxyAddresses) {
    Write-Host "WARNING: User $($user.Name) found with proxyAddresses not set."
}
```